# Multiple IIF statements in SSRS for same column

Tags: reporting-services, iif

I am trying to use below query on a column in SSRS reporting and it throws an error.Please help me fix this

```
=IIF((9(Fields!Project_ID.Value = "41-116") OR (Fields!Project_ID.Value = "41-116BP1")
OR (Fields!Project_ID.Value = "41-117")  OR (Fields!Project_ID.Value = "41-17")
OR (Fields!Project_ID.Value = "41-17-F") OR (Fields!Project_ID.Value = "41-181")
OR (Fields!Project_ID.Value = "41-19") OR (Fields!Project_ID.Value = "41-201")
OR (Fields!Project_ID.Value = "41-30") OR (Fields!Project_ID.Value = "41-30-A")
OR (Fields!Project_ID.Value = "41-6045") OR (Fields!Project_ID.Value = "41-80")
OR (Fields!Project_ID.Value = "36-1002") OR (Fields!Project_ID.Value = "36-37")
OR (Fields!Project_ID.Value = "45-120X01") OR (Fields!Project_ID.Value = "31-09")
OR (Fields!Project_ID.Value = "35-20-A") OR (Fields!Project_ID.Value = "35-20-N")
OR (Fields!Project_ID.Value = "42-66-1") OR (Fields!Project_ID.Value = "42-66-2")
OR (Fields!Project_ID.Value = "Goleta") OR (Fields!Project_ID.Value = "Playa Del Rey")
OR (Fields!Project_ID.Value = "1014")) ,"N/A",Fields!Permit.Value),(Fields!Project_ID.Value = "44-137") OR (Fields!Project_ID.Value = "43-121"),"NR",Fields!Permit.Value))
```

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: It says ')' is missing.As you see for few values I need them updated as "N/A" and for few "N/R" and the rest the original value from the db table

Answer (score 2):

The if statement above works well! -As an alternative, you can also do a Switch statement:

```
=SWITCH(
    Fields!Project_ID.Value = "41-116"
 OR Fields!Project_ID.Value = "41-116BP1"
 OR Fields!Project_ID.Value = "41-117"
 OR Fields!Project_ID.Value = "41-17"
 OR Fields!Project_ID.Value = "41-17-F"
 OR Fields!Project_ID.Value = "41-181"
 OR Fields!Project_ID.Value = "41-19"
 OR Fields!Project_ID.Value = "41-201"
 OR Fields!Project_ID.Value = "41-30"
 OR Fields!Project_ID.Value = "41-30-A"
 OR Fields!Project_ID.Value = "41-6045"
 OR Fields!Project_ID.Value = "41-80"
 OR Fields!Project_ID.Value = "36-1002"
 OR Fields!Project_ID.Value = "36-37"
 OR Fields!Project_ID.Value = "45-120X01"
 OR Fields!Project_ID.Value = "31-09"
 OR Fields!Project_ID.Value = "35-20-A"
 OR Fields!Project_ID.Value = "35-20-N"
 OR Fields!Project_ID.Value = "42-66-1"
 OR Fields!Project_ID.Value = "42-66-2"
 OR Fields!Project_ID.Value = "Goleta"
 OR Fields!Project_ID.Value = "Playa Del Rey"
 OR Fields!Project_ID.Value = "1014", "N/A",

    Fields!Project_ID.Value = "44-137"
 OR Fields!Project_ID.Value = "43-121","NR",

    TRUE, Fields!Permit.Value    
)
```

I added spaces so you can see where each 'section' is.. the True at the end works as the 'else'.

Answer (score 1):

Try ..

```
    =IIF(((Fields!Project_ID.Value = "41-116") OR (Fields!Project_ID.Value = "41-116BP1")
OR (Fields!Project_ID.Value = "41-117")  OR (Fields!Project_ID.Value = "41-17")
OR (Fields!Project_ID.Value = "41-17-F") OR (Fields!Project_ID.Value = "41-181")
OR (Fields!Project_ID.Value = "41-19") OR (Fields!Project_ID.Value = "41-201")
OR (Fields!Project_ID.Value = "41-30") OR (Fields!Project_ID.Value = "41-30-A")
OR (Fields!Project_ID.Value = "41-6045") OR (Fields!Project_ID.Value = "41-80")
OR (Fields!Project_ID.Value = "36-1002") OR (Fields!Project_ID.Value = "36-37")
OR (Fields!Project_ID.Value = "45-120X01") OR (Fields!Project_ID.Value = "31-09")
OR (Fields!Project_ID.Value = "35-20-A") OR (Fields!Project_ID.Value = "35-20-N")
OR (Fields!Project_ID.Value = "42-66-1") OR (Fields!Project_ID.Value = "42-66-2")
OR (Fields!Project_ID.Value = "Goleta") OR (Fields!Project_ID.Value = "Playa Del Rey")
OR (Fields!Project_ID.Value = "1014")) ,"N/A",IIF((Fields!Project_ID.Value = "44-137") OR (Fields!Project_ID.Value = "43-121"),"NR",Fields!Permit.Value))
```

Comment: Thank you all for the quick response. Your suggestions worked!!